# CVS checkout from Windows command line Windows

Tags: command-line, cvs, vcs-checkout

Is there a way to check out from CVS using Windows command line (cmd) given the branch, package, and destination dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cvs -q -d <CVSROOT> co -r <BRANCH> -d <DESTINATION> <PACKAGE>
```

Answer (score 0):

CVS is a monolithic executable, which doesn't have an API as such. 
So to execute  a CVS command, you use std::system( "cvs command params" ) or similar, just as you would have done from the command line.

Comment: I know that I should use the system(char*) command. Just was looking for the right string command.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question then, removing references to C++ and VS, which have nothing to do with the issue.