# CVS Checkout in Windows from Linux Samba CVSROOT

Tags: linux, windows, cvs

I need to checkout from a CVS base in Linux, on a Windows machine with a directory link to a samba folder on Linux. In Linux, my `cvsroot` folder is

```
mylogin$ cd /home/myuser/repositories/cvsroot
mylogin$ ls
CVSROOT PRJ1 PRJ2
mylogin$
```

which is mapped from Samba. On Windows, it is mapped to a drive z: from `/home/myuser/repositories/`. Also on Windows, my CVSROOT environment variable is configured as `CVSROOT=z:\cvsroot`.

So, for checking out PRJ1 on a Windows folder, I tried

```
cvs co PRJ1 .
```

and it returned me the error message

> cvs [checkout aborted]: Failed to resolve path: `Z:\cvsroot': No such file or di
>   rectory

So, what did I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try checking out using the actual network share path instead of the mapped drive? In other words `export CVSROOT=\\1.2.3.4\cvsroot ` and then `cvs co PROJ1`?

Comment: Yes. It returns me `cvs [checkout aborted]: \\serverip\cvsroot/CVSROOT: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the answer.

The post from [cvs checkout from windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286786/cvs-checkout-from-windows-command-line) helped me. So I used

```
cvs -q -d /cygdrive/z/cvsroot co -d . PRJ1
```

and it worked.